# How do I optimize this SQL query

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

Running this on MySQL 5 (Amazon RDS) on a large instance (i.e. very powerful), this query takes 16 seconds to execute. This InnoDB table has about 2 million rows.

```
DELETE FROM quiz_multichoice_user_answer_multi WHERE
user_answer_id IN( SELECT id FROM
quiz_multichoice_user_answers WHERE question_nid =
1001700 AND question_vid = 1002731 AND result_id =
64003
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it to use JOINs instead of a subquery and see if that improves things. It often does with MySQL; the query planner is better at optimizing joins, and choosing good indexes when they're used, for whatever reason.

```
DELETE 
  quiz_multichoice_user_answer_multi
FROM
  quiz_multichoice_user_answer_multi
INNER JOIN
  quiz_multichoice_user_answers
ON
  quiz_multichoice_user_answer_multi.user_answer_id = quiz_multichoice_user_answers.id
WHERE
  quiz_multichoice_user_answers.question_nid = 1001700
AND
  quiz_multichoice_user_answers.question_vid = 1002731
AND
  quiz_multichoice_user_answers.result_id = 64003
```

Comment: Can I just check, quiz_multichoice_user_answer_multi after the DELETE shouldn't be there?

Comment: I tested the SELECT analogue of this query and it was mighty quick compared with the equivalent for the original. (using SQL_NOC_CACHE)

Comment: I believe it should be there. It specifies the table to delete from in a `DELETE` query which references multiple tables. I was looking at the `DELETE` manual page when I wrote it.

Comment: Quite right; I will continue to test and get back to this thread ASAP! Thanks a million! :-)

Comment: This appears to be the winning solution! This has cut it down from several seconds to a few milliseconds.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this was solution was finally committed to an open source project, on this thread: http://drupal.org/node/947190 - thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Are your columns indexed?
How many rows do you expect this to affect? If its only one, then try adding `LIMIT 1` at the end, so it wont have to look for other rows after it deletes the first one

Also try using EXPLAIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure how the query could be optimized as its pretty simple now, you are only selecting the data needed etc.

Maybe a better approach would be to look at optimizing the database structure?

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.